# How to convert column of arrays of strings to strings?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column, which is of type `array < string >` in spark tables. I am using SQL to query these spark tables. I wanted to convert the `array < string >` into `string`.

When used the below syntax:

```
select cast(rate_plan_code  as string) as new_rate_plan  from
customer_activity_searches group by rate_plan_code
```

`rate_plan_code` column  has following values:

```
["AAA","RACK","SMOBIX","SMOBPX"] 
["LPCT","RACK"]
["LFTIN","RACK","SMOBIX","SMOBPX"]
["LTGD","RACK"] 
["RACK","LEARLI","NHDP","LADV","LADV2"]
```

following are populated in the `new_rate_plan` column:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@e4273d9f
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@c1ade2ff
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@4f378397
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@d1c81377
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@552f3317
```

Cast seem to work when I am converting `decimal` to `int` or `int` to `double`, but not in this case. Curious why the cast is not not working here. 
Greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Spark 2.1+ to do the concatenation of the values in a single Array column you can use the following:

1. `concat_ws` standard function
2. `map` operator
3. a user-defined function (UDF)

### concat_ws Standard Function

Use [concat_ws](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@concat_ws(sep:String,exprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function.

> **concat_ws(sep: String, exprs: Column*): Column** Concatenates multiple input string columns together into a single string column, using the given separator.

```
val solution = words.withColumn("codes", concat_ws(" ", $"rate_plan_code"))
scala> solution.show
+--------------+-----------+
|         words|      codes|
+--------------+-----------+
|[hello, world]|hello world|
+--------------+-----------+
```

### map Operator

Use [map](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@map[U](func:T=%3EU)(implicitevidence$6:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]) operator to have full control of what and how should be transformed.

> **map[U](func: (T) ⇒ U): Dataset[U]** Returns a new Dataset that contains the result of applying func to each element.

```
scala> codes.show(false)
+---+---------------------------+
|id |rate_plan_code             |
+---+---------------------------+
|0  |[AAA, RACK, SMOBIX, SMOBPX]|
+---+---------------------------+

val codesAsSingleString = codes.as[(Long, Array[String])]
  .map { case (id, codes) => (id, codes.mkString(", ")) }
  .toDF("id", "codes")

scala> codesAsSingleString.show(false)
+---+-------------------------+
|id |codes                    |
+---+-------------------------+
|0  |AAA, RACK, SMOBIX, SMOBPX|
+---+-------------------------+

scala> codesAsSingleString.printSchema
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- codes: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: How to achieve the same with pyspark? convert a spark df column with array of strings to concatenated string for each index?

Comment: @Tracy No idea. I'd recommend asking a separate question to reach out to the pyspark devs community.

Answer (score 8):

In spark 2.1+, you can directly use concat_ws to convert(concat with seperator) string/array< String > into String .

```
select concat_ws(',',rate_plan_code) as new_rate_plan  from
customer_activity_searches group by rate_plan_code
```

This will give you response like:

```
AAA,RACK,SMOBIX,SMOBPX 
LPCT,RACK
LFTIN,RACK,SMOBIX,SMOBPX
LTGD,RACK 
RACK,LEARLI,NHDP,LADV,LADV2
```

PS : concat_ws doesn't works with like array< Long > ..., for which UDF or map would be the only option as told by Jacek.

Answer (score 3):

You can cast array to string at **create this df** not at output

```
newdf = df.groupBy('aaa')
  .agg(F.collect_list('bbb').("string").alias('ccc'))

outputdf = newdf.select(
  F.concat_ws(', ' , newdf.aaa, F.format_string('xxxxx(%s)', newdf.ccc)))
```

Comment: sorry to ask a newbie question .... what is F in above code ?

Comment: For @Lav comment , I know its too late to answer now but if anybody is still looking for and f is alias for spark function. You use it when you declare your spark function Import like this "from pyspark.sql import functions as F"

Answer (score 1):

The way to do what you want in SQL is to use the inbuilt sql function [string()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#string)

```
select string(rate_plan_code) as new_rate_plan  from
customer_activity_searches group by rate_plan_code
```