# Error in converting pyspark column of array of string to a string on databricks

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to convert a pyspark dataframe column from array of string to a string.

df:

```
 text
 [this, is, a, book, that, I, like]
```

I need:

```
 text
 "this, is, a, book, that, I, like"
```

Based on [How to convert column of arrays of strings to strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924762/how-to-convert-column-of-arrays-of-strings-to-strings),

My py3 code:

```
  import pyspark.sql.functions as F
  t = df.withColumn('text', F.concat_ws(", ", df.text))
```

error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I missed something ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're intending to join an array of strings, not to concatenate multiple columns (which is what `concat_ws` expects).

The code you're looking for is `F.array_join(df['text'], ', ')`

```
df.withColumn('text2', f.array_join(df['text'], ', ')).show(truncate=False)
```

```
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|text                              |text2                           |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|[this, is, a, book, that, I, like]|this, is, a, book, that, I, like|
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```